# SQL Server Extract Data Model

Tags: sql-server, model, visio, enterprise-architect

Is there a simple way of extracting the database model of existing DBs? I played around in the management studio and in Visio, even though I found very interesting features of data integration I failed to perform a simple export of the structure of the DB.

Could anyone pls give me a hint how to perform such an export, basically I only need the table and view names and their fields in a Visio or Enterprise Architect readable format.

thx in advance

K

Comment: Are you referring to Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

thanks guys for the presented hints.

I figured around and found that Visio 2k7 has a pretty easy to use
DB reverse engineering functionallity which actually resolved my
problem. It works with MS SQL and also with ODBC.

To make it short: Visio ships with the needed functionallity,
Enterprise Architect 7.1 has a quite similar functionallity
which makes use of ODBC too.

K

Answer (score 1):

Exporting schema is easy with Tasks->Generate Scripts...
but wheter you can use it with Visio - no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Select the "Generate Scripts" option from your Object Explorer:

[image]

and then make sure to pick "Generate all objects" from the Script Wizard:

[image]

This allows you to create a single SQL file to create the whole database, and at least Visio Enterprise is able to reverse-engineer a database from a SQL script.

Marc